# Powershell - Appending to existing DataSet

Tags: powershell, datatable, dataset

I have in powershell (1.0) a SQL statement that return a DataSet. Now I run this SQL statement in a loop an iterate over a parameter. I want to append the DataSet returned from my function Exec-SQL-Query to existing DataSet from previous call...how can I do that? I tried doing stuff with DataTables and DataSet but didn't work.

```
foreach ($id in $idList)
                {               
                    $Parameters.Add($parameterKey,"$id")
                    $dataSet = Exec-SQL-Query -SqlCmd $sqlCmd -Parameter $Parameters -SqlConn $conn
                    # I would like to do something like:
                    #$dataSet.Add($dataSet.Tables[0])
                    $Parameters = @{}
                    $i++
                }
```

The function Exec-Sql-Query works fine , already tested it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're just trying to append the table from the returned dataset to your original dataset.  This won't work because you're wiping out $dataset every time you call to your database.

Instead, declare an empty dataset outside of your loop and add the returned table to it instead.

```
$myDataSet = New-Object System.Data.Dataset

foreach ($id in $idList)
            {               
                $Parameters.Add($parameterKey,"$id")
                $dataSet = Exec-SQL-Query -SqlCmd $sqlCmd -Parameter $Parameters -SqlConn $conn

                # Now add the returned table to $myDataSet:
                $myDataSet.Tables.Add($dataSet.Tables[0])
                $Parameters = @{}
                $i++
            }
```

This will result in a dataset with multiple tables.

I don't have a way to test this, but if you're determined to append to $dataset and $dataset has already been instantiated elsewhere, you might also try this:

```
$dataset.Tables.Add((Exec-SQL-Query -SqlCmd $sqlCmd -Parameter $Parameters -SqlConn $conn).Tables[0])
```

I'd be curious to know if that works. Let me know.